# Laravel Nova: Queuable actions create single job for multiple resources

Tags: queue, laravel-nova

I have a simple Action in Laravel Nova which updates stock inventory via an API call. I want to be able to queue this as individual jobs for each product that requires an update to stagger the API calls.

When I add my action to a resource and run it via the index page by selecting multiple products and running the action, only a single job is created in my jobs table.

So when the queue is processed, rather than queuing each product for an individual update, a single job is run which loops all selected products and makes multiple API requests in quick succession, which is not my desired result.

Is there a way for the action to create a job for each resource that the action is run against?

**Action Class**

```
class UpdateInventory extends Action implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->connection = config('queue.default');
        $this->queue = 'inventory_update';
    }

    /**
     * Perform the action on the given models.
     */
    public function handle(ActionFields $fields, Collection $products)
    {
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            try {
                $inventoryService = resolve(InventoryService::class);
                $inventoryService->updateProductInventory($product); // <- API calls within
                $this->markAsFinished($product);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $this->markAsFailed($product, $e);
            }
        }

        return Action::message("Inventory update started");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class UpdateInventory extends Action implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

        /**
         * The number of models that should be included in each chunk.
         *
         * @var int
         */
        public static $chunkCount = 1;

}
```

Comment: Please improve your answer by adding a small note on how and why this solves the problem or question. Code snippets only usually don't help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You may instruct Nova to your queue actions as a batch. That requires migration so you create batches table with following command `php artisan queue:batches-table` and migrate your database. This table contains `total_jobs`, `pending_jobs`, `failed_jobs`, `failed_job_ids` fields so you can keep track each job. If each job has one resource, it should resolve your issue.

More information:
[Laravel Nova Actions - Job Batching](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/4.0/actions/defining-actions.html#job-batching)
[Laravel Queues - Job Batching](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#job-batching)